# Run an expression rowwise for its side-effect only

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I often want to run an expression or call a function on each row of a tibble purely for the side-effect, without any interest in the return value. For example, I might have a tibble with a list column of data that I want to save using file names from a character column. There are of course a myriad ways to do this, but I would prefer to do it as elegantly as the other rowwise operations in dplyr (1.0). Essentially, I'm looking for an amalgam of rowwise `mutate()` and `purrr::walk()`. Here's an ugly approximation to what I want to do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- 
  tibble(file = c("iris.csv", "mtcars.csv"),
         data = list(iris, mtcars))
dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(x = list(write_csv(data, file))) %>% invisible()
```

Is there a way I can do away with the `x = list(…)` stuff and explicit hiding of the return value while maintaining easy access to the "data-variables" in the function call (without ugly stuff like `.x$data[[1]]`)? Suppose there was such a function (`walk_rows()`?) I would expect to use it something like this:

```r
dat %>% walk_rows(write_csv(data, file)))
```

I know I can do this:

```r
dat %>% pwalk(function(dat, file) write_csv(dat, file))
```

But having to write the names of the data-variables twice is inelegant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear if you're looking for something that's already within the tidyverse that allows what you want, or whether you're looking for an implementation of `walk_rows`. I'm not aware of anything in the tidyverse that does exactly what you want, but here's an implementation of `walk_rows`:

```
walk_rows <- function(dat, expr)
{
  `%>%` <- dplyr::`%>%`
  m <- as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  dummy <- dat %>% 
    dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(x = list(eval(m$expr)), .groups = "drop")
}
```

So you can do:

```
dat %>% walk_rows(write.csv(data, file))
```

Which quietly writes your files. Or, for example:

```
dat %>% walk_rows(print(paste0(file, ": ", nrow(data))))
#> [1] "iris.csv: 150"
#> [1] "mtcars.csv: 32"
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been more clear, what I was looking for was: ideally, something already in the tidyverse that allows me to do what I want directly, or failing that, an elegant way of using some other tidyverse functionality to accomplish the same goal. Your implementation is fine though. Would you mind if it used it in a feature request for dplyr?

Comment: @UliKeller I don't mind you pointing to the question / answer as a feature request,  though I suspect it won't be considered a great idea (I can't quite put my finger on it, but the syntax doesn't feel idiomatic to me). Also the name might be better like `do_rowwise()` or `map_rowwise` since I would have no idea from the name `walk_rows` what the function did.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wasn't going to propose this exact solution, just use it as an example. I would just like to have this functionality in the tidyverse somehow, I don't really care about the name of the function or the syntax. Do you happen to have an idea for a more idiomatic syntax?

Comment: @UliKeller this is effectively a mapping function for scalar inputs and outputs. Tidyverse mapping functions take functions as arguments rather than unevaluated calls (you have already given an example of a rowwise mapping function that takes a function instead of a call). I think there is a case to be made for the function you propose, but I'm not sure the developers would agree - it can do no harm to ask!

Answer (score 1):

[`group_walk`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html) seems to be the current dplyr way to do this. In the example from the question:

```r
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_walk(~ write_csv(.$data[[1]], .$file)))
```

or, using an explicit function instead of the purrr-style formula:

```r
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_walk(function(row, key) { write_csv(row$data[[1]], row$file) })
```

or, if you don't like the `$`s,

```r
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_walk(function(row, key) {
    with(row, {
      write_csv(data[[1]], file)
    })
  })
```

Notes:

- I'm not sure why we need the `[[1]]`; without it, `data` is a one-element `list`.
- This feels way more verbose than the OP's `mutate`.
- `group_walk` is lifecycle:experimental.
- Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628505/69707) which outlined this approach.